# Controlling page length

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I want to circulate a Word 2007 document, with a page within it, that people can add to, but I do not want the total content of that page to be able to continue on to another page. When that page is full, is there a way of preventing addition of further text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to get the effect that you want (or at least close)
by creating a table with one row and one column;
then formatting the row to **not** “Allow row to break across pages”. 
I don’t know how to prevent the *addition* of further text,
but only the first nine inches’ worth (i.e., one page) will display. 
The rest will scroll off the bottom of the page/table,
not to be seen again (until text above it is deleted).

Comment: Many thanks, Scott. That meets the practicalities.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) If you believe that one answer provides the best solution to your problem, you can _accept_ it by clicking on the check mark to the left.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things come to mind.  The first won't prevent entry of additional text but will prevent the contents from exceeding the page.  Create a text box that fills the area where you want people to enter text.  It will act like a fixed window onto whatever text is there.  Whatever text doesn't fit in the window will not be displayed and won't trigger new pages.

Another approach would be to experiment with a full page "form entry".  I'm not sure about the form controls in Word 2007, but typical controls include the ability to limit things like the number of characters (figure out how many characters of typical text will fit in the area desired).